# Related to partially ordered field (poset) and total ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, ordered-fields

(i) Let K be a field with the property that there is a positive natural number m such that $m * 1 = 0$. Show that there is no total order that gives K the structure of an ordered field.

(ii) Show that for every finite field (a field whose underlying set is finite) there exists a positive natural number m such that $m * 1 = 0$

(iii) Conclude that the concept of the scalar product cannot be analogous to the real and complex cases of vector spaces over finite field. This is especially the case for bodies of the form $F_{p}$.

How can a positive natural number multiplied by one equals to zero? I am puzzled about this whole concept. Please explain in details.

Comment: In (i) should "ordered set" be "ordered field" instead?

Comment: Are you familiar with arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}/2$? Here $1 + 1 = 0$. Do you see how it might be reasonable to say $2 \cdot 1 = 0$ in this case? In general, do you see that in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ we have $p \cdot 1 = 0$? It turns out the same is true in some fields other than $\mathbb{Z}/p$ as well.

Comment: I agree, though, that this notation is a little bit abusive. When we say "a positive natural number $m$ with $m \cdot 1 = 0$, we mean for this to be repeated addition. Add $1$ to itself $m$ times. This is not to be confused with multiplication _inside_ the field.

Comment: There is a hint to solve this question using the recursive sequence? I wonder how we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"multiplication of numbers" is actually a relative concept, depending on the algebraic structure which you are working with. For your question, the most important example is
$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}
$ which is a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) (with mod $p$ summation and multiplication).For example when $p = 5$ we have this equalities (in $
\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}
$):
$$
1+1+1+1+1 = 5 = 5*1 = 0 (mod \text{ }5)
$$
so you see that $5*1 = 0$ in this context.

Now, I will go through (i), (ii) and (iii):

(i): Defining axioms of an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) (F, +, ., <) imply that for any $0 \ne x \in F$ we have $x^2 > 0$ because if $x > 0$ we get $x*x = x^2 > 0$ and if $x < 0$ we have $x + (-x) < 0 + -x$ so $0 < -x$ and then again we have $x^2 = (-x)*(-x) > 0$ and we are done. so in a special case, we get $1 > 0$ in  any ordered field (F, +, ., <). Now if we have some positive $m$ which $m*1 = 0$, we will get a contradiction, because:
$$
1>0 , 1+1>0, 1+1+1>0, ..., 0 = 1+1+...+1(m\text{ times}) > 0
$$

(ii): Assuming $F$ is a finite field with cardinality $n$, if we add up $1$:
$$
1, 1+1, ..., 1+1+...+1(n+1 \text{ times})
$$
we have to get two equal numbers in this sequence like $m*1 = p*1$ and $m \ne p$ so we get $(m-p)*1 = 0$.

(iii): This part is straight. if we look at [vector space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), we see from that (i) and (ii) its not possible to define scalar product for a finite field $F$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as usual, like: $1_{\mathbb{R}}*1_{F} = 1_{F}$ because then we will have some $m \in \mathbb{Z}\text{: } m*1_F = 0_F$ and:
$$
0_F = \frac{1}{m} * 0 = \frac{1}{m}(m*1) = 1_{\mathbb{R}}*1_{F} = 1_{F}
$$
which is absurd.